# How to render component’s JSX child elements

Tags: reactjs

I have a code to run app like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import AComponent from './components/AComponent'

render(
<AComponent>
  <span id="needShow">HTML inner Component Tag</span>
</AComponent>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And this is component code:

```js
import React from 'react'
const AComponent = () => (
  <div>
      <span> Hello of AComponent</span>
  </div>
)

export default AComponent
```

How can I show span with the id `needShow`?

Comment: @AndrewL. You can, but it's not done very often, see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child components are passed to a component via the `children` prop:

```
const AComponent = (props) => (
  <div>
      {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I'm new for React and your help save me and others so much time.